# Ubuntu 13.04 Server Installation With no RAID option?

Tags: installation, server, raid

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.04 Server. When I get to the partition manager, I select `Manual`. When I click on one of my disks that I want to use as a RAID partition, the option doesn't exist.

Can you not create a RAID in the Ubuntu installation any more, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

#### Just overlooking something?

These are screenshots during the installation of the `ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso` in a virtual machine to test:

[image]

[image]

Note that, as guntbert says a comment, these options only exist when the disks have a Partition table, which new disks don't have. Therefore, for completely new disks, the first step must be: `<enter>` on each disk, confirm "create a PT".

Comment: Those options do not exists on my installation...

Comment: @makoReactor Then please elaborate more on your installation CD. What exact ISO are you using? Anything custom/beta perhaps? What option did you choose in the initial boot screen? Etc. etc.

Comment: Those options only exist when the disks have a Partition table, which new disks don't have. Therefor the 1st step must be: <enter> on each disk, confirm "create a PT".