# Setting Up RAID During 13.04 Install

Tags: installation, partitioning, raid, lvm

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop on [RAID 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5), but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have read that it can be done during the install, though I haven't found a good explanation of how it is done. I saw something about using LVM and the 'physical volume for RAID' options, but I can't find the 'physical volume for RAID' in the list of options for the new partition.

I found [this installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/i386/ch06s03.html#di-partition) ,  but none of the RAID options can be found. Does anyone have a screen shot or something that might help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also: [Ubuntu 13.04 Server Installation With no RAID option?](http://askubuntu.com/q/291568/88802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test these steps to be able to verify 100%.

I think the way you can accomplish it, is by booting from the Ubuntu 13.04 DVD, or USB flash drive, and choosing try Ubuntu.  Once the desktop comes up, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo -i
```

This saves you from having to type 'sudo' in front of every command.  Then, start 'cfdisk' with the device name of the first harddisk:

```
cfdisk /dev/sda
```

Install mdadm and configure the RAID array.

To complete the setup, and for more information, and detailed steps click [here](http://www.michielovertoom.com/linux/ubuntu-software-raid/) or [here](http://zackreed.me/articles/38-software-raid-5-in-debian-with-mdadm).

<sup>Source:[ubuntu-software-raid](http://www.michielovertoom.com/linux/ubuntu-software-raid/)</sup>

Comment: The link talks about a RAID1. I was wanting to do a RAID5.

Comment: @DogLover I've added a second link to an older article covering mdadm and RAID 5.

Answer (score 4):

For a RAID option during installation using Raring 13.04 media, your best bet is the minimal ISO, either 32-bit or 64-bit.  These ISO's are a text-based installer which will present you with the option for Software RAID during the install.  You must select the "Manual" partition option to be able to select Software RAID.

Keep in mind that these ISO's require an active internet connection during the installation process.  The installer downloads many of the required packages including the desktop flavour of your choice and some additional add-on's, if chosen hence the term, "minimal".

The Software RAID option was to be included in Ubiquity for the Raring 13.04 desktop installer, but it is simply not there and there has been no notable news about this for the time being.

The minimal ISO links for Raring follow below,

[Raring Minimal 32-bit ISO](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

[Raring Minimal 64-bit ISO](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

Comment: This is much simpler than the "Try Ubuntu" route.