# Does the Ubuntu Server iso support full disk encryption out of the box?

Tags: server, system-installation, encryption

Does the Ubuntu Server iso support full disk encryption out of the box?

If no, what options do I have to do this out of the box with a stock ISO now that alternate got nuked?

Comment: What version of ubuntu server are you specifically targeting?

Comment: [Yes it does support LVM/Encryption/RAID](http://askubuntu.com/a/291582/88802). Haven't you even tried booting up a server ISO? The server ISO is now the alternative to the alternate installer image now unavailable since 12.10. Just use the server ISO and you can activate "manual package selection" and pick the desktop environment you want.

Comment: @gertvdijk I haven't tried downloading it without confirmation because I'm on metered internet...and this isn't flagposted anywhere I could find without a 700 MB download.

Comment: @gertvdijk okay the word encryption is not in there anywhere, so google and site search don't find it in the pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the Ubuntu 13.04 Server ISO. The installer *does offer* the option to create an Encrypted Volume.

I can't confirm that it works properly, since I am having some issues with grub2 and dual-booting.

EDIT: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/293029/62612) offers working command line instructions for encrypting the filesystem root.